# how to calculate distance from a given latitude and longitude on the earth to a specific geostationary satellite

Tags: spherical-geometry

As the title suggests, I would like to know how to calculate the straight-line distance from a given latitude+longitude point on the earth to a given satellite in the geostationary belt.   Perhaps a simplification would be to provide the geostationary sub-point on the equator.  Or, is that a complication?  :-)

Sorry, I'm a computer programmer and not much of a geometry person.  If there is an on-line calculator that does this, feel free to provide a link.  I've been unable to find a straightforward answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let us pick a coordinate system centered at the center of the earth, with $+x$ through the satellite (so longitudes will be measured relative to the satellite)  and $+z$ through the north pole.  Let $\phi$ be the latitude of the ground station and $\lambda$ the difference in longitudes.  The satellite location is $(R_s,0,0)$ where $R_s$ is geosynchronous radius, about $42164$ km.  The ground station location is $(R_e \cos \lambda \cos \phi, R_e \sin \lambda \cos \phi, R_e \sin \phi)$ where $R_e$ is the radius of the earth, about $6367$ km.  This uses a spherical earth-you can get more accurate is you use a more accurate shape of the earth.  The next step is the [reference ellipsoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_ellipsoid).  Then you can just use the Pythagorean theorem for the distance:  $d^2=(R_s-R_e \cos \lambda \cos \phi)^2+(R_e \sin \lambda \cos \phi)^2+(R_e \sin \phi)^2$.  The earth radius varies by about $\pm 11 $km, so that is the order of the error you make by using a spherical earth.

Comment: This question is specifically asking for Geo-satellites, but for other satellites (MEO & LEO), how will the equation change. Should I ask a separate question regarding this

Comment: @KharoBangdo:  It doesn't change at all.  You just need to adjust $R_s$ to reflect the distance from the center of the earth to the satellite.

Comment: @KharoBangdo but it does depend on the fact that the GEO satellite is over the equator.  It becomes more complicated if the radius vector is not perpendicular to the North axis.